# Can't install zbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to use the qrtools module with Python 3.4.2 on my Raspberry Pi 2, however it cannot run as I don't have the `zbar` module installed. 
Trying

```
pip-3.2 install zbar
```

Gives the error message shown in the picture

```
sudo pip-3.2 install zbar
```

gives a similar error

Any ideas?

(I do have it installed with Python 2.7)
[image]

UPDATE: Both libzbar-dev and python3-dev are up to date. Still...

```
No module named  'zbar'
```

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/p/zbar/bugs/86/

Comment: is this screen captured from a phone serious?

Answer (score 16):

assuming you're using a debian derivative (like ubuntu), you need to install `zbar`'s developement package, which contains the header file `zbar.h`

```
$ sudo apt-get install libzbar-dev
```

for redhat/fedora systems:

```
$ sudo yum install zbar-devel
```

and *probably* python's dev package too:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Comment: That should read `apt-get install`, not `apt install`. And that will only work if the Pi is running some variant of Debian.

Comment: Does it give the same error? `#include <zbar.h>` not found?

Comment: @STOMO7 you're right, the build doesn't succeed. You have two options now - install python2 version using `apt-get install python-zbar python-qrtools` or create an issue at zbar's github/bug tracker and hope the developer to respond

Comment: @AyushShanker it installed fine however python3 said 'No module named zbar' still

Comment: @STOMO7 the build failed for me in python3, succeeded in python2

Comment: On ubuntu, having the `sudo apt-get install python-zbar libzbar-dev python-qrtools` and then `pip install libzbar-cffi==0.2.1` solves the issue

Answer (score 2):

or you can use pip install zbar-py
https://pypi.org/project/zbar-py/

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code after entering sudo mode:
yum install zbar-devel
This should work for fedora.

Answer (score -1):

Bumping @herve solution

On ubuntu and on Mint

`sudo apt-get install python-zbar libzbar-dev python-qrtools`

`pip install libzbar-cffi==0.2.1`