# AttributeError: module 'zbar' has no attribute 'ImageScanner'

Tags: python, python-3.x, zbar

I try to run this code

```
import pyqrcode
from qrtools import qrtools
from PIL import Image
import zbar
qr = pyqrcode.create("She got two litle horns and they get me a litle bit")
qr.png("horn.png", scale=6)
qr = qrtools.QR()
scanner = zbar.Scanner()
qr.decode("horn.png")
print(qr.data)
```

And it says to me

```
AttributeError: module 'zbar' has no attribute 'ImageScanner'
```

Im running the latest ubuntu x64 and have all dependencies installed mayby is because im trying on python3

Comment: Can you add the output of a `pip3 freeze`?  It looks like the `zbar` package on PyPI was last updated in 2009, so it's certainly possible it doesn't work under Python 3.  https://pypi.org/project/zbar/

Comment: I´m sorry how?, im a newbie

Comment: Just open a terminal and run these 2 commands: `pip2 freeze` and `pip3 freeze`.  And also `python --version`.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Q3L7PgVJ

Comment: Python 3.6.5 and Python 2.7.15rc1

Comment: and this one from freeze pip2 https://pastebin.com/T4mXaVUt

Comment: Edit: Okay it looks like you've installed the package `zbar-py` (different than the `zbar` one I mentioned above) in the Python 3 virtual environment but not the Python 2 one.   But in the Python 2 one you have separately installed a different package called `zbar`.  If you run your script using `python3 foo.py` do you still get the error?

Comment: it runs without issue on python2

Comment: yeah i still get it

Comment: Okay, it looks like zbar-py installed on python 3 includes zbar (https://github.com/zplab/zbar-py/blob/master/README.md).  Can you verify that your Ubuntu version includes the iconv library required by zbar-py?

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install libzbar-dev` then re-running with python3.

Comment: yeah it seems like i don't have it

Comment: libzbar-dev is already the newest version (0.10+doc-10.1build2).

Comment: Hmm.  It seems like you have everything setup correctly.  You might open an issue on the zbar-py library on GitHub and link them back here to see if we've missed something.

Comment: Also try this `sudo apt-get install libc6-dev`.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/898826/why-is-there-no-libiconv-package-in-ubuntu

Comment: libc6-dev is already the newest version (2.27-3ubuntu1).

Comment: Hmm.  That seems right.  Maybe `sudo apt-get install libzbar0`.  https://www.learnopencv.com/barcode-and-qr-code-scanner-using-zbar-and-opencv/

Comment: It looks like there's another alternative zbar PyPI wrapper package for Python 3 - `pyzbar`.  Try that one instead. https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar

Comment: actually it seems that worked

Comment: The code has run to anoter problem now Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project.py", line 7, in <module>
    qr = qrtools.QR()
AttributeError: module 'qrtools' has no attribute 'QR'
but i will check it later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have to use python2 and install zbar with ubuntu package manager

```
sudo apt-get install python-zbar
```

I tested it on my Ubuntu 17.10 machine and it worked with python2. Python3 doesn't seem to work though, see here, they have the same issue: [Can't install zbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34577710/cant-install-zbar)

Make sure you are running the right python version by typing this in the terminal:

```
 python --version
```

It has to say: Python 2.7.X where X is 14 on my machine

Comment: it seems like so